# Docker swarm: public service not reachable from inside container of the same deployment

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode

My Setup: I have a single machine docker swarm "cluster". 
Simply said, I have a stack deployment that is composed of two services A and B. Both services are connected (through an external overlay network) to another stack running a traefik proxy to expose those services to the public.
**I can reach both services via their traefik routing from my browser.**

What doesn't work though:
**I can not reach service A from within service B using A's public domain** (via its traefik routing). I always get a connection timeout when attempting a HTTP call.

I this some regular expected behavior that can be fixed with some option or is my setup somehow broken? I read that `endpoint_mode: dnsrr` might help in some situations of this kind but it really didn't make a difference for me. I tried it on both services as well as on the traefik service.

I don't want to overwhelm you with all the configuration details of my machine and swarm deployments right here as that might be overkill if I just made a configuration mistake that's obvious from my problem description.

For the ambitious reader, here are some further details:

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 125
  Running: 59
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 66
 Images: 328
 Server Version: 19.03.8
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: loki
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: juwtdqk60ufj3rityctog7ev0
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: 3mte2zcw4nfc1jq17dzwvtoi3
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 178.254.21.80
  Manager Addresses:
   178.254.21.80:2377
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-96-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 31.41GiB
 Name: rv1324
 ID: L7JD:POVR:EPMY:JGMF:3BFX:DQJA:B5KK:O3PG:YH44:TNLJ:YD3I:GROZ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

The swarm stack I'm trying to deploy can be found here
https://github.com/skuzzle/cmp/blob/0f8004b41f1a486fee7b6705c4bcbc39a2414412/swarm-stack/feature.yml
The connectivity problem is between the `cmpauthorization` and the `cpmfrontend` service. In order to finish an OAuth2 authorization process, the latter service needs to send a POST request to the authorization service's public domain.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that it is a firewall issue. I'm running ufw on the machine but I have yet to find out how to properly configure it for docker swarm. Just opening the swarm management ports doesn't help